# Pre selected option highlighted grey on page load, want it to be blue

Tags: css, background-color, select-options

for example, when you go to the page below with this code, upon load option one is selected and has a background color of grey.  When I click it it turns blue.  How can I have it that blue when the page loads, not grey.

```
<select class="select" multiple="multiple" id="select_id">
<option selected>option one</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: adding a style inline to the option like <option style="background-color: blue;" selected>Option One</option> does not do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override background color of selected value like this:

```css
select option:checked{ 
  background: lightgreen -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, lightgreen 0%, lightgreen 100%);
}
```

```html
<select class="select" multiple="multiple" id="select_id">
    <option selected>option one</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: weird though,  it worked on my local code but when I pushed it up to dev and beta it did not work?   But this helped a lot and I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Dylano236  try to refresh cache of your browser

Comment: @Dylano236   https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/672607/how-to-hard-refresh-your-web-browser-to-bypass-your-cache/amp/

Comment: yea it's not a cache issue.  cache was cleared.  It's some server or browser issue.  Annoying!

Comment: ended up being a difference in the main js file in dev and beta that was different from prod and local.  Figured it out.